# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, database, reference, foreign-keys

I need help...while creating a database I kept running into this error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`accident_db`.`participated`, CONSTRAINT `participated_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`license`) REFERENCES `car` (`license`))
```

The problem come in hand when I try to insert into participated. I Tried making the whole database over, coding it a diff way, checking the spelling, and other grammar errors.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  driver_id VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(25),
  address VARCHAR(40)
) engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE car (
  license VARCHAR(8),
  model VARCHAR(15),
  year date,
  PRIMARY KEY(license)
) engine=innodb;


CREATE TABLE accident (
  report_id VARCHAR(6),
  date date,
  location VARCHAR(25),
  PRIMARY KEY(report_id)
) engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE owns (
  driver_id VARCHAR(9),
  license VARCHAR(8),
  FOREIGN KEY(driver_id) REFERENCES person(driver_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(license) REFERENCES car(license),
  PRIMARY KEY(driver_id, license)
) engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE participated (
  driver_id VARCHAR(9),
  license VARCHAR(8) ,
  report_id VARCHAR(6),
  damage_amount decimal(10,2),
  FOREIGN KEY(driver_id) REFERENCES person(driver_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(license) REFERENCES car(license),
  FOREIGN KEY(report_id) REFERENCES accident(report_id),
  PRIMARY KEY(driver_id, license,report_id)
) engine=innodb;


    insert into person values('DRIVER001','John Smith','Tech, TN');
    insert into car values('AABB2000','BMW','2001');
    insert into accident values('AR2197','2014-04-08','Cookeville TN');
    insert into owns values('DRIVER001','AABB2000');
    insert into participated values('DRIVER002','AR2197','CCDD3000','1500');
```

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to your error messages.

```
insert into person values('DRIVER001','John Smith','Tech, TN');
```

You inserted 'DRIVER001'.

```
insert into participated values('DRIVER002','AR2197','CCDD3000','1500');
```

But this row tries to reference 'DRIVER002'. Fixing this will lead you to *another* FK error, though. The license doesn't exist, either.

When you insert rows, it's best practice to list the columns after the table. Keep them in table order, so it's easier to see where you're going wrong.  (We often omit the column list in SO answers for brevity, and to make it easier to focus on the *real* problem.)

The following insert statement should succeed. If you *really* want to insert data form DRIVER002, or for license CCDD3000, you'll need to insert those values into "person" and "car" first.

```
insert into participated (driver_id, license, report_id, damage_amount) 
values('DRIVER001','AABB2000','AR2197','1500');
```

---

As a separate issue, the column "year" should be an integer, not a date.

```
CREATE TABLE car (
  license VARCHAR(8),
  model VARCHAR(15),
  year date,
  PRIMARY KEY(license)
) engine=innodb;
```

The insert statement for an integer year is different.

```
insert into car values('AABB2000','BMW','2001');  -- Not this
insert into car values('AABB2000','BMW', 2001);   -- But this
```

The integer year isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know how the primary key and foreign key works. If you want to insert a data to a particalar field which is a foreign key, it'll lookup for the same data in its reference table's primary key field. If it matches, it'll add. If it doesn't match, the error will occur as you stated. Like Mike Sherrill said, you should change it to

```
insert into participated (driver_id, license, report_id, damage_amount)
values('DRIVER001','AABB2000','AR2197','1500');
```